# python pexpect sudo su - appluser

Tags: python, pexpect

I am trying to provide password for "sudo su - appluser" account via python script

```
import pexpect
chld = pexpect.spawn('sudo su - appluser')
chld.expect('[sudo] password for rajesh:')
chld.sendline('XXX')
#print chld.before
```

But i am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 3, in <module>
    child = pexpect.spawn('sudo su - appluser')
  File "/users/rajesh/pexpect/__init__.py", line 511, in __init__
    self._spawn(command, args)
  File "/users/rajesh/pexpect/__init__.py", line 616, in _spawn
    'executable: %s.' % self.command)
pexpect.ExceptionPexpect: The command was not found or was not executable: sudo.
```

can you please check this and correct me here

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution ? If yes, can you please post it because I am getting the same error. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Try to use absolute path to sudo command (/usr/bin/sudo).